# 1D moving sofa problem

Tags: geometry

Could the famous "Moving sofa problem" be stated for a 1D curve instead of a 2D area, where instead of the area to be maximized, we want the length to be maximized (only roughly analogous to the Sofaproblem ofc) as follows?:

"What is the maximum length continuous curve that can be moved around a rectangular bend of unit thickness and has at most curvature $\kappa$? (The curvature limitation is to eliminate trivial solutions)

for $\kappa=0$ $L=2\sqrt2$

for $\kappa=\frac{1}{R}$ and $R=2+\sqrt2$  I have a quarter-circle of radius R